# Need help redirecting one website URL to another with apache2 and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have two domains - https://hosting.opensimcity.org, and http://paradigm.pocketmud.com and I want to redirect the latter to the former. That is, when someone connects to http://paradigm.pocketmud.com I want it to redirect to https://hosting.opensimcity.org/paradigm

Any tips on doing this in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following htaccess redirect code:

```
Redirect 301 / https://hosting.opensimcity.org/paradigm
```

This 301 redirect response notifies the search engines that the page has moved permanently from the old URL to the new URL. The search engines also transfer the old URL page rank to the new URL.